# Correct use of std::move in the code snippet

Tags: c++

I have to return m_message in the snippet below. Since its a unique_ptr, i am moving it to another unique_ptr and returning that instead. But I get this compilation error -
What is my mistake here ?

```
error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = tev::events::EventMessage; _Dp = std::default_delete<tev::events::EventMessage>]’
   53 |      std::unique_ptr<EventMessage> ret_m_message = std::move(m_message);
      |
```

```
class EventBase
{
public:
     .
     .
     .
    /*

    /* RBN - Need to access m_message for debugging */
    std::unique_ptr<EventMessage>               GetEventMessage() const
    {
            std::unique_ptr<EventMessage> ret_m_message = std::move(m_message);
            return ret_m_message;
    }

private:
    .
    .
    .

    std::unique_ptr<EventMessage> const m_message;
    bool m_Property;
};
```

Comment: Moving `const` item is... copying.

Comment: `EventMessage* GetEventMessage() const { return m_message.get();}` seems sufficient for debugging.

Comment: Moving a `const` member variable in `const` member function seems suspect.

Comment: @Jarod42 I bet this is better: `const EventMessage* GetEventMessage() const { return m_message.get();}`

Comment: @Ben: Then [`std::experimental::propagate_const<std::unique_ptr<EvenMessage>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/propagate_const) might be useful.